# webrtc no packets from browser

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, wireshark

I'm trying to connect webrtc with my asterisk server. Using Asterisk 12.8 and simpl5. I hear no sound on both sides. Wireshark shows udp packets coming from asterisk but no packets from browser. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall and NAT settings of Asterisk. Go through the sip debug logs.